# Sort numbers in an structure - Visual Net

Tags: vb.net

I have this structure:

```
Module Module1
    Structure alumnos
        Dim nombre As String, universidad As String, ciudad As String, notaone As Double, notatwo As Double, notathree As Double, promedio As Double

    End Structure
```

How Can I sort my structure  by the variable "promedio" in descent order.

I tried `Array.Sort` but I don't know how to insert the variable of my structure into that.

Comment: Presumably you have a `List(Of alumnos)`, in which case you can use `.Sort` with a suitable comparer: [List(Of T).Sort Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Also, a `Class` is likely to be a better choice than a `Structure`.

Comment: Actually I want to show the structure in a data gried view but just the TOP THREE notas, so I want to order  and then show just the three first elements.

Comment: See my answer, think that would do it.

Comment: So sort them and then use `.Take(3)`. [Enumerable.Take(Of TSource) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim lstAlumnos As List(Of alumnos) = Foo() ' Foo brings a list
lstAlumnos = lstAlumnos.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.promedio).Take(3).ToList
```